# Python 3, create new dictionary using list and another dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, replace

Could you help me wiht my issue ? Let's say that I have few list with ID's their members, like below:

`team_A = [1,2,3,4,5]`

`team_B = [6,7,8,9,10]`

`team_C = [11,12,13,14,15]`

and now I have a dictionary with their values:

`dictionary = {5:23, 10:68, 15:68, 4:1, 9:37, 14:21, 3:987, 8:3, 13:14, 2:98, 7:74, 12:47, 1:37, 6:82, 11:99}`

I would like to take correct elements from dictionary and create new dictionary for team A, B and C, like below:

`team_A_values = {5:23, 4:1, 3:987, 2:98, 1:37}`

Could you give advice how to do that ? Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you already tried? What errors are you encountering with that approach? If you have no idea where to start, you can look into loops and iterators.

Comment: I was trying to use for to dau that like below: 

`for i in dictionary_id_value:       
        if i in dictionary_id_value.keys():
            team_A_values.update(i)`

but it doesn't work and it shows error: TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below by just Iterating through the lists

```
team_A = [1,2,3,4,5]

team_B = [6,7,8,9,10]

team_C = [11,12,13,14,15]

dictionary = {5:23, 10:68, 15:68, 4:1, 9:37, 14:21, 3:987, 8:3, 13:14, 2:98, 7:74, 12:47, 1:37, 6:82, 11:99}

team_A_values  = {}

for i in team_A:
    team_A_values[i] = dictionary[i]

print(team_A_values )
```

can repeat this to team B and team C

in that case you can do like this

```
team_values = [{i: dictionary[i] for i in team_A },{i: dictionary[i] for i in team_B},{i: dictionary[i] for i in team_C}]
teamA,teamB,teamC = team_values
print(team_values)
print(teamA)
print(teamB)
print(teamC)
```

in one line you can do like this

```
team_values = [{i: dictionary[i] for i in team } for team in [team_A ,team_B ,team_C]]
teamA,teamB,teamC = team_values
print(team_values)
print(teamA)
print(teamB)
print(teamC)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works. But do you know perhaps the way how to do that for all 3 teams using one cod and not repeat the whole block of cod for rest of teams ?